# How do I avoid generating 3 numbers instead of generating 3 letters and numbers together

Tags: python, if-statement

This is a code that generates 3 random letters, numbers, and symbols. I tried to put the "if" formula to avoid the dot at the end of the 3-letter word, and it worked for me:

```
if password[length-1] == dot:
        dot_password = password.replace(password[length-1],"" .join(random.sample(alll,new_length)))
        file.write(dot_password+"\n")
```

But when I tried to avoid generating 3 numbers only, I failed to do so:

```
elif password == NUMBERS:
        number_password = password.replace(password,"" .join(random.sample(allll,length)))
        file.write(number_password+"\n")
```

That's why I'm here to find a solution with you. For information, this is the Python language

This is the complete code:

```
import random

file = open(r"C:\******\******\******\******\******\******\******\Users.txt", "r+")

for i in range(10000): # I set it to 10000 to test only.
    lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_"
    NUMBERS = "0123456789"
    dot = "."

    all = lower + NUMBERS + dot
    alll = lower + NUMBERS
    allll = lower + dot
    length = 3
    new_length = 1
    password = "".join(random.sample(all,length))

    if password[length-1] == dot:
        dot_password = password.replace(password[length-1],"" .join(random.sample(alll,new_length)))
        file.write(dot_password+"\n")
    elif password == NUMBERS:
        number_password = password.replace(password,"" .join(random.sample(allll,length)))
        file.write(number_password+"\n")
    else:
        file.write(password+"\n")
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?  What exactly is the criteria for a 'good password' in your code?  Why do you add 'Dot' if you're only going to take it off again?

Comment: Does changing `password == NUMBERS` to `password.isdecimal()` fix your problem?

Comment: I want to generate passwords with Letters, Numbers, and Symbols. But under certain conditions, it is that the end of the password does not contain a dot and that the password does not contain numbers only. The reason for putting a dot is to generate the password with a dot, but not at the end of the word. and when I used ```password.isdecimal()``` it being generated less than before like 3 to 8 numbers only of 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NUMBERS = '0123456789'`
here NUMBERS is a string that is numeric

`elif password == NUMBERS:`
here password must be '0123456789' for this condition to be true

This is why the above code is not working.

Could try

```
   elif password.is_numeric():
```

to test if the whole password just contains numbers

Comment: I used your method and it works but it still generates 3 numbers but less than before.
Before using your method, 3 numbers of 10000 . were generated (from 120 to 180) - 
After using your method, it generates (from 3 to 7) 3 numbers out of 10000,

So this is another problem

Comment: can iterate a string to analyse the characters, eg for ch in password: if ch...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know if the generated password contains only numbers:

```
def is_all_number(password):
    numbers = '1234567890'
    for i in password:
        if not i in numbers:
            return False
    return True
```

Then you can use it inside your condition:

```
if is_all_number(password):
    ...
```

Or you can use `password.isdecimal()` as the condition.

Comment: I used ```password.isdecimal()``` and it works but it still generates 3 numbers but less than before. like **InhirCode** Problem